# How to draw an infinite line at a specific degree angle (e.g. 270W) using Apple MapKit?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location, mkpolyline

I've read the docs on [MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html) and can't find any API for drawing fixed width lines at specific degree angles in the mapView's coordinate system (so my lines rotate when the user rotates the map (to stay in sync with the degree angle they represent)). This must be possible right? Any ideas?

UPDATE 1:

I've looked into `MKPolyline` and only see API for `polylineWithPoints:count:` and `polylineWithCoordinates:count:` but nothing for "line at degree angle" such as 270. I need the line to draw all the way around the globe through my current location. The compass app shows angles of degree and I need to represent an angle of degree in the mapView through my current location. What am I missing?

UPDATE 2:

In the following image you can see the TOP of the screen is 270° W and the RIGHT of the screen is 0° N. How do I draw a line that intersects my current location and extends in a straight line at 270° W as depicted in the image below?
[image: Desired Outcome as Screenshot]

Comment: You are describing an MKPolyline overlay.

Comment: Okay. I'll look into `MKPolyline`. Thanks.

Comment: I only see `polylineWithPoints:count:` and `polylineWithCoordinates:count:`. No API for polylineForDegreeeAngle:. I would think I could call something like `MKPolyline *line270 = [MKPolyline polylineForDegreeAngle:270];`. But that doesn't seem to exit. What am I missing? @matt

Comment: Ah. Well, I guess I was thinking you would convert from your desired angle to points lying on a line at runs at that angle. No?

Comment: Is that the best way to do it when I need the line to run all the way around the globe through my current location?

Comment: Where were you able to find the docs on converting angles to points that run a specific angle? I will look into this!

Comment: I do not know what you think you mean by angle. You are drawing on a sphere that has been projected onto a rectangle. I don't understand what you think you're going to do. What I'm telling you is how to draw a line that is effective drawn on the earth, so that it travels with the map.

Comment: My mental model must be off. Thanks for the description. I'll adjust to that mindset.

Comment: @matt I added a screenshot that helps to better describe my objective. Any ideas on how to get started accomplishing this goal?

Comment: I still don't get it. What does "I need the line to draw all the way around the globe through my current location" mean? What does "all the way around" mean? The globe is a sphere. Longitude lines are great circles, but latitude lines are not; nevertheless they both go "all the way around" in some sense. Moreover, the line goes in only one direction in your screen shot, so clearly it is not a great circle (or _any_ circle) going all the way round the globe; if it were, it come back around and come in from the bottom. Your words make no sense as they stand.

Comment: Another problem is what you mean by "direction". I know what it means to take a bearing from where I am at an angle of 270 degrees, but what the "line" does on the surface of the earth after traveling any significant distance from me is not at all clear. This, after all, is what the rhumb line problem is all about. And then, don't forget that in the map view, the world is projected flat. It seems to me that you need to spend some quality time with Ptolemy and Mercator before you can enunciate any goals at all.

Comment: That is _why_ polylines are defined in terms of connecting two _coordinates_ on the surface of the globe: that is a definition that makes unambiguous sense. So the answer to your question is: pick a distant point that is, in whatever sense you have in mind, on this same 270 degree line as your starting point, and connect that point with your starting point with a polyline or a geodesic line. And that is the answer I gave at the outset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are speaking in terms of an angle specified by degrees of a circle, it sounds like you want to do plane geometry.

The easiest way to do that on a map view is with MKMapPoints. Translate the coordinate of your starting point into a map point with MKMapPointForCoordinate; now pick another MKMapPoint at some distance away and at the angle you want; and connect them with an MKPolyline that you show as an overlay to the map.

Translating the notion "an angle of n degrees from my point and north" into a point on the line that runs away from your point at that angle is then a trivial matter of elementary plane trigonometry.